# Why stdout won't flush when redirecting input from a fifo?

Tags: stdout, stdin, fifo

I have a program that displays a prompt message and waits for the user to input some text.

```
$ program
Input a line of text: <aaaa>
Some more output.
$
```

Now, I also want to be able to provide this input, programmatically, via a FIFO, like so:

```
$ program < fifo
```

But what's happening is, the prompt on stdout does not appear until I have supplied the input to `fifo`.

I next tried a very simple equivalent of my program, like so:

```
$ echo aaaa < fifo
```

Even here, `aaaa` doesn't appear until `fifo` has been supplied its input.

**Question:** How do I make my output till the point I wait for input from `stdin` appear on `stdout` when using FIFO?

Comment: The script/program doesn't even _start_ to execute until there is data in the pipe. Also, unrelated to your issue: Prompting should _always_ be done on the standard _error_ stream, not and standard output.

Comment: That's (shocking) news to me! Why should the program not even start? If the input were coming in from a regular disk file (and, not from a fifo), would the same semantics of program execution hold? Input should get read ONLY when it's needed, not before. So, a reading from fifo should block only on reaching the point of input in the program, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FIFO is opened by the shell, but the opening of it is blocking until the FIFO is opened for writing by some other process.  Since redirections are processed *before* the execution of the command, the program is not even executed until the shell's `open()` call returns. This is documented behaviour for [the `open()` C library function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/open.html) (used by the shell):

> `O_NONBLOCK`
>
> When opening a FIFO with `O_RDONLY` or `O_WRONLY` set:
>
> - If `O_NONBLOCK` is set, an `open()` for reading-only
>                          shall return without delay. An `open()` for writing-only shall return an error if no process currently
>                          has the file open for reading.
> - If `O_NONBLOCK` is clear, an `open()` for reading-only
>                          **shall block the calling thread until a thread opens
>                          the file for writing**. An `open()` for writing-only
>                          shall block the calling thread until a thread opens
>                          the file for reading.

So the shell is obviously not using `O_NONBLOCK` when it's opening the FIFO.

Solution:

1. `cat fifo | program`

   `cat` reads from the FIFO until end-of-file, then exits.
2. `tail -f fifo | program`

   `tail` reads from the FIFO until end-of-file, then hangs around to wait for more until terminated.

Which of these is best suited to your situation depends a bit on what's writing to the FIFO at the other end, and how it does the writing.

Third solution involves having the program opening the FIFO when needed.

---

According to [the Rationale section on `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_18), a shell must set standard input to blocking because...

> If the shell did not reset this flag, it would immediately terminate because no input data would be available yet and that would be considered the same as end-of-file.

Comment: FIFOs on Linux and FreeBSD can be opened in `O_RDWR` mode, yielding a third choice.

Comment: Hmh, as for the last quote, wouldn't the `read()` on the pipe just block until a writer comes along. Or should I say "couldn't it". That's what  seems to happen on Linux anyway, if you open in read-write mode... except then it never gives an EOF condition. Logically enough, the same process is a writer too.